# How to setup JSFiddle for use with Kendo Dataviz?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, jsfiddle, kendo-dataviz

I have the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rodneyhickman/NYh2b/1/ I'm trying to set it up to test some Kendo UI DataViz graphs.

I'm getting the following script errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined kendo.all.min.js:9
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined kendo.dataviz.min.js:10
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that version of kendo may use a different version of jquery than the one you're loading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things.  If you are referencing the kendo.all.min.js, you don't need any other .js files, it has all of them included (dataviz, web and mobile).  Also you need to include the dataviz.common.css and dataviz.THEMENAME.css (I included default).  Also switch back to jquery 1.9.1 and it should work fine.

```
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a forked jsfiddle.   http://jsfiddle.net/fWG9R/  (I used the latest version 2013.3.1119)

If you want to include other components from web or mobile, you will need to include the kendo.common.css, and kendo.THEMENAME.css, and kendo.mobile.css respectively.